# Infinite Loop of two ajax calls keep loading the page and not call success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I run two functions that each one of this run ajax call in it. And if the call was a success it calls that function again (infinite loop).
I need that infinite loop because `PHP` side gets an information from `json` that can change every second.

So here's the issue: I open site, the page keeps loading and ajax calls don't execute the code in `success`. **BUT** if I refresh the page a several times, it ** doesn't** keep loading and it executes the code in `success` but it won't have been working for so long and it doesn't execute the code in `success`.

*Error function doesn't log anything as if it was a success.*

Here's the code:

```
function startAjax(offset=0, status=0) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/handler.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { offset: offset, status: status },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.game_status == "planned") {
                setInterval(function() {
                    var currentDate = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
                    var newDate = (data.start_time - currentDate) * 1000;
                    $('#game_countdown').html(getFormattedDate(newDate));
                }, 1000);
                $('#game_countdown').show();
            } else {
                if (data.status == 1) {
                    $('#game_countdown').hide();
                    $('.answer').css('background-color', '');
                    $('#question').show();
                    $('#question').html(data.id + ') ' + data.question);
                    $('#answer_1').html(data.first);
                    $('#answer_2').html(data.second);
                    $('#answer_3').html(data.third);
                    $('#answers_block').show();
                    $('.answer').removeClass("active");
                    $('#answer_'+data.answer_id).addClass("active");
                    document.title = data.answer_id + '. ' + $('#answer_' + data.answer_id).text();
                } else if (data.status == 2) {
                    $('#game_countdown').html("Ожидание вопросов...");
                    $('#game_countdown').show();
                } else if (data.status == 3) {
                    console.log("RIGHT ANSWER");
                    console.log(data.right_answer);
                    var element = $('#answer_'+data.right_answer);
                    if (element.hasClass('active')) {
                        element.removeClass('active');
                    }
                    element.css('background-color', 'lime');
                }
            }
            startAjax(data.offset, data.status);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("ERROR!");
            console.log(error.responseText);
            $('#connect-error').show();
        }
    });
}

function startSearch(offset=0) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/search.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { offset: offset },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if ($('.search-button').hasClass('active')) {
                if (data.status == 1) {
                    switch ($('.search-button.active').attr('id')) {
                        case "s1":
                        window.open("https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&q="+data.question);
                        break;
                        case "s2":
                        window.open("https://www.google.ru/search?hl=ru&q="+data.question+" "+data.first+" "+data.second+" "+data.third);
                        break;
                        case "s3":
                        window.open("https://yandex.ru/search/?text="+data.question);
                        break;
                        case "s4":
                        window.open("https://yandex.ru/search/?text="+data.question+" "+data.first+" "+data.second+" "+data.third);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            startSearch(data.offset);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("ERROR!");
            console.log(error.responseText);
            $('#connect-error').show();
        }
    });
}

startSearch();
startAjax();
```

Comment: Don't reload the page, just update a section of it with the response!

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL I'm afraid I don't get you. Doesn't ajax already update a section without reload?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what problem I had... `livereload` script at the end of `body` was causing of that problem.. I would never thought it could be problem